# Keras in python 2 environment conda with ImportError: cannot import name np_utils

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I try to run in python2 which is environment of conda.

Since I cannot install keras via pip and conda install, I install by this command `conda install -c conda-forge keras`.

I think this is the problem, because I have another computer that can install keras via pip and this problem does not occur.

```
import lstm, time #helper libraries
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation, Dropout
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
from keras.models import Sequential


#Step 1 Load Data
X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = lstm.load_data('sp500.csv', 50, True)

#Step 2 Build Model
model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(
    input_dim=1,
    output_dim=50,
    return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(LSTM(
    100,
    return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(
    output_dim=1))
model.add(Activation('linear'))

start = time.time()
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='rmsprop')
print 'compilation time : ', time.time() - start

#Step 3 Train the model
model.fit(
    X_train,
    y_train,
    batch_size=512,
    nb_epoch=1,
    validation_split=0.05)

#Step 4 - Plot the predictions!
predictions = lstm.predict_sequences_multiple(model, X_test, 50, 50)
lstm.plot_results_multiple(predictions, y_test, 50)
```

and I got this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name np_utils
```

Comment: What is version of keras that you are using ? Try to import number before you import anything from Keras. I was facing the same issue, importing numpy before importing numpy utilities ( np_utils ) solved the issue

Comment: "I" is always uppercase on English.

Comment: I use keras2.0.6. And i tried the way that you said. It still be the same. Calvin Duy Canh Tran